# How to implement scaling behavior without scaling the texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, cg

Good day! So the question is how to implement the next behavior: I have game object in 2D project that scales over time to one side (actually scales in both sides but also moves towards the scale direction) you can see it on gif below (not allowed directly paste gifs yet)

[Scaling of platform below the player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKHru.gif)

If i attach texture (sprite?) it will scale with object as well - this is not what i'm attempting to do. One solution is to set **Clamp** or **Repeat** parameter in the texture inspector. But it's also not acceptable for me. I don't know how exactly to explain what i want to do... but lets imagine that i have the final texture invisible and during the scaling of object new parts of that texture becomes visible. You can see that behavior on next gif.

[Actual behavior that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSJZO.gif)

I guess i need some kind of shader that implements it so please provide me with that script ( i'm totally new to shaders coding, only know the basics). Take on account that I'm going to animate the texture that will be attached to scaling object, maybe it also will affect the shader script. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to have a defined start/end on the left/right of your floors, you can use the world x position in your shader for the uv.x coordinate with a texture which will loop. keep in mind that ths method won't work for floor if you intend to rotate them at any point and that will be much more involved.

Code below should work for a very basic sample of your your looking for (note the vertex shader section).

```
struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = float2(v.vertex.x, v.uv.y);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
        }
```